# OSX Custom URI Scheme - Multiple Copies of Same App

Tags: macos

I have a custom URI Scheme associated with my app (configured in the info.plist) and all works well. I'm now trying to debug an issue and struggling to get the system to launch my debug version of the app (I have numerous other versions elsewhere on disk and it keeps launching one of those.) Anyone know how to associate the URI scheme with a specific path to an app - or to ensure that my debug version is the one launched?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's nothing like posting a question to make you think of the answer. The solution is to rebuild the launch services database, then ensure that your debug version is the first to be run (thus registering its scheme.) The way to rebuild the launch database is as below:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user